# Warning! The maximum key length is 900 bytes. The index has maximum length of 8009 bytes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-administration

I have a temporary variable with a computed column based on SHA1 hasbyte. When I create a UNIQUE non clustered index on the computed column, it throws the warning::

> Warning! The maximum key length is 900 bytes. The index 'UQ__#B445E45__954B055AC5951B75' has maximum length of 8009 bytes. For some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail.

I remember reading out put of SHA1 byte being limited to some 160 bytes. I'm unable to understand why I get this warning.

If check the max length of all the columns involved in computed column by the below query it adds up to some 8148 bytes. But i thought with the hash I'm using I should get not more than 160 bytes for the computed column.

```
SELECT Sum(c.max_length)
FROM SYS.COLUMNS C INNER JOIN SYS.TABLES tb ON tb.[object_id] = C.  [object_id]
INNER JOIN SYS.TYPES T ON C.system_type_id = T.user_type_id
WHERE tb.[is_ms_shipped] = 0
and OBJECT_NAME(tb.object_id)='xyz'
```

Please advise what I'm missing here.

Comment: show us your computed column?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza My computed column looks like: CompSum  AS HashBytes('SHA1', Col1+ Col2+ Col3+.. 15 more column) . All the columns included in the computed column are varchar(n) where n not more than 50

Comment: Yes, but db doesnt know that. You need to include a casting otherwise he assume the biggest `n` allowed

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza You mean to say, the Unique constraint I'm adding will not understand that the hashbyte will be no more than160 bytes and I need to add a CAST cap of the Computed column so that the contraint will not show up the warning?

Comment: It's just a warning. If you know the output can't exceed 900 bytes then just ignore the warning.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Hi there, big fan here :)

Comment: Thank you @AaronBertrand! I think I'm good to ignore the warning then!

Comment: Thank you @JuanCarlosOropeza for the quick response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not expert on Hash:

But I suggest you create a column `combine varchar(750)` (15*50)

Then update that column with `SET combine = Col1+ Col2+ Col3+.. Col15`

And try:

```
CompSum AS HashBytes('SHA1', combine)
```

That way you are using a field which will never be bigger than 750

Comment: Actually `varbinary(20)` would probably be a better choice (try it out and you'll see why). But I would probably do `CompSum AS CONVERT(varbinary(20), HashBytes('SHA1', col1+col2+...)` rather than add an additional computed column.

Comment: @AaronBertrand yes, that work better. Mine was just a suggestion to test if that would solve the warning.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes just a simple CONVERT eliminates the warning!